# Apache mod_rewrite query string before page and remove extention

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've scavenged the web for answers to my mod_rewrite woes and I feel I'm at the end of my wits.  I will have a URL like such: `http://www.website.com/dashboard.php?username=stackoverflow`.  This url isn't the prettiest of such.  So my goal is to do a few things here...

1. Eliminate the extension of the php file (I've been able to do this so far with the code I'll show below, but I don't know that it will stay according to the other things I need to do)
2. Eliminate the "www" prefix
3. Move the username query string (only if it's "username", I don't want to match "id" or such) directly after ".com/"
4. Move the php filename (without the extension) after query string.

The final URL should look like such: `http://website.com/stackoverflow/dashboard` or perhaps `http://website.com/stackoverflow/profile`.

The code I have right now which eliminates the file extension is such:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

# remove .php ONLY if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.php\sHTTP/1)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# remove trailing slash ONLY if it is not an existing folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# rewrite to FILENAME.php if such file does exist and is not a folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Sadly this only fixes one of my issues and after looking at it, I'm getting the feeling there would be a better way to do this...

Comment: I'd suggest you to read the very interesting "optimizing website" rules of the YSlow plugin, and you may probably guess why it's a bad idea to remove "www", *unless* your static content points to another domain name.

Comment: Ahh, good point Olivier... that's a good point.  Thank you!

Comment: Read this very good answer here about www: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/www-yoursite-com-or-http-yoursite-com-which-one-is-futureproof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1, 3, 4) As I understand you want to use pretty URLs, but backed by PHP pages. So it should be like this:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(\w+)/profile$ /dashboard.php?username=$1 [L]
```

It will make `http://website.com/stackoverflow/profile` working as `http://www.website.com/dashboard.php?username=stackoverflow`

(2) 
     # Redirect www.site.com to site.com with 301

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What if instead I wanted to have a single page (for instance: home.php) which would then load the contents of dashboard.php or profile.php depending on if statements I write.  The URL would look something like http://website.com/stackoverflow.  Would that be possible with the rules you've written above?

Comment: Yes. E.g. RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /home.php?username=$1 [L] The (\w+) pattern can be different of course. But you need to make sure, that your patterns are not ambiguous. This might be tricky - but you can organize links in way you want using these types of rewrites. I use this approach for my site.

Comment: Wonderful answer Eugene.  Thanks for your help!